# Redirecting website to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I've been issued with an SSL certificate via 123-Reg, which I've approved, and now 123-Reg have advised I have to update my .htaccess file with the necessary to re-route all http requests to https.

The problem is that every time I update .htaccess, the website goes down.

Looking around, it seems that I should post the following at the top of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

So, my current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 30 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I've tried with the above code, and just the Rewrite code on its own, but to no avail.  It should be noted that I'm not particularly au fait with the intricacies of using .htaccess!

The error message I'm receiving (in IE Edge) is:

```
Hmmm... cannot reach this page
Try this
Make sure that you’ve got the right web address: https://www.pixel8games.com
Search for "https://www.pixel8games.com" on Bing
Refresh the page
Details 
There were too many redirections.
Error Code: INET_E_REDIRECT_FAILED
```

I can also manually enter the https address in the url without issue when the redirect code isn't in .htaccess.

If anyone can assist, I'd be most grateful.
Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and put the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this doesn't assist in all the instances I have (IE Edge, Chrome Desktop & Mobile, Opera and Firefox).  They all state that the site is redirecting too many times.

Comment: see update , clear your browser cache first and test it

Comment: Yes I did all of what you advised on your post but the issue remains, unfortunately.